# How to use a LINQ query to include index in Select with F#

Tags: c#, linq, f#

I have this code sample in C#, which outputs index and value from the array:

```
static void Sample_Select_Lambda_Indexed()
{
    string[] arr = { "my", "three", "words" };

    var res = arr.Select((a, i) => new
    {
        Index = i,
        Val = a
    });

    foreach(var element in res)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", element.Index, element.Val));
}
```

Output is:

```
0: my
1: three
2: words
```

I want to make a similar query in F#, and have started like this:

```ml
let arr = [|"my"; "three"; "words"|]

let res = query {
    for a in arr do
    // ???
}
```

How would I finish this LINQ query?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Seq.mapi`:

```
let res = arr |> Seq.mapi (fun i a -> ...)
```

or just use `Seq.iteri` directly:

```
arr |> Seq.iteri (fun i v -> printfn "%i: %s" i v)
```

or just:

```
arr |> Seq.iteri (printfn "%i: %s")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to do this with a LINQ query if possible?

Comment: You can totally call `.Select` from F#,  just like you do from C# (just make sure to `open System.Linq`). Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @brinch - As far as I know F# query expressions don't support it.

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin: Nope, I'm looking for the query way of doing this :-) Like I started with in my question and didn't finish.

Comment: You cannot do this with query syntax, just like you cannot do this with LINQ syntax in either C# or VB.NET.

Comment: @brinch to rephrase Fyodor Soikin's comment, your C# example calls the Enumerable.Select method; it doesn't use a C# query comprehension.  Similarly, to do this in F#, you need to call the desired Enumerable.Select overload explicitly, rather than using an F# query expression.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
let arr = [|"my"; "three"; "words"|]
let res = Array.mapi(fun index value -> (index, value)) arr

for (index, value) in res do
    printfn "%i: %s" index value
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there not a way to do this with a LINQ query?

Comment: @brinch: Not sure actually, I'm not an F# expert :)

Comment: F# doesn't have LINQ, only C# and VB.NET do. Also, the code in your question is not LINQ,  you're just calling `.Select`.  Why is it ok for you to call `.Select ` in  C#,  but not ok to call another function in F#?

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin: According to this, LINQ is indeed possible in F#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374.aspx

I know my C# example is using a lambda expression, but I would like to know how this can be done with a LINQ query in F#.

Comment: That author of that article probably meant to say "_...provides support equivalent to what LINQ provides in C#_". The acronym "LINQ" really only refers to C#'s and VB's compherensions for `SelectMany` et al. Mapping with index is not possible in F#'s query expressions, just as it is not possible in C#/VB's LINQ.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I don't think it's inappropriate to refer to F#'s query expressions as "LINQ."  From the documentation: "Query expressions provide support for LINQ in F#." (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Linq:

```
open System.Linq

let Sample_Select_Lambda_Indexed = 
    let arr = [| "my"; "three"; "words" |]
    let res = arr.Select(fun a i  -> i,a)
    res.ToList().ForEach(fun el -> let x,y = el in printfn "%i - %s" x y )
```

Print:

```
0 - my
1 - three
2 - words
```

Link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uQfoI1

But I don't see any advantage of Linq in this case